# What could be the right powersource for 15 seconds lifespan disposable giant chainsaw?

Tags: technology, science-fiction, energy

Imagine when a jet fighter swoops in to drop a 400 pounds giant chainsaw to you just so that you can use it to grind down one problematic enemy into a pulp then discard it a foot away from you. What power source would suit such a weapon with only 1 instant use before breaking itself apart?

Comment: This whole concept seems unwise to me.  400lbs is crazy amount of weight to wield, which assume the chainsaw survives landing, and it lands near you.  Range is way too close to have a problematic enemy for my comfort.  Instead how about 100lbs or so of frag grenades or similar you can use from a safe distance.  Range, damages, easy to use, and multiples can be deployed to same target easily.

Comment: @cybernard The whole concept is *batshit insane*. It's obviously intended for a fictional universe driven by the [rule of cool](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool) and not by rationality.

Comment: @Philipp So you will be dead/injured, but "rule of cool" because you got to close to the beast and it got in a fatal strike/counter strike  against you.  However, since I attacked from a distance I will be alive.  I would rather be alive than cool in that case.

Comment: @Philipp there is rule of cool and there's stuff that breaks the suspension of disbelief. I do believe that with chainsaw planes, any hope for realism goes right out the window... which doesn't necessarily make the resulting fiction bad, but it does make the need for defined inner workings quite a bit less necessary.

Comment: In a universe where coolness trumps sanity when it comes to conflict, chainsaw planes make perfect sense. As do superhero landings (They’re hell on the knees), giant floating air fortresses and flashy uniforms with the underpants on the outside. Basically this is the kind of thing *any* superhero film could benefit from.

Comment: @JoeBloggs you know, I can buy mithril-infused skeletal structure of your everyday superhero. The idea that the ground can survive the impact is far less likely. Heck, even a Nokia 3310 dropped from one meter can dent a sidewalk...

Comment: Look at Turbonique for inspiration. Their idea was to mount the front half of a rocket engine to the back half of a turbocharger, so that you turn fuel into horsepower instead of thrust. They were very successful in the 60's drag racing scene! https://jalopnik.com/video-the-demented-rocket-propelled-genius-of-turboniq-5481005

Comment: I initially read this as the jet dropping the chainsaw directly on the enemy, which is also awesome.

Comment: @TKK just as unrealistic though. Not the carrying a running chainsaw on an airplane, but it's pretty much impossible to aim it from any reasonable height. Unpredictable wind currents will ruin your precision - it's a near-solid block of metal, but the precision required is too high. The spinning blade does fun things to aerodynamics as well, which means unpredictable coefficient of drag as well as landing orientation. You want it to land blade first, not just bonk your enemy with a heavy object in the head.

Comment: I feel compelled to point out a useful fact: once the chainsaw is completely discharged, it can be disassembled into its component parts. You now have the bar and chain to a 400 pound assault weapon at your disposal. Assuming it was even remotely useful against armored targets and not just a bombastic terror weapon, they are made of neat stuff, are heavy, and are in the hands of a combatant who can wield a 400 pound chainsaw. The spring engine could also justifiably be described as wildly dangerous if ever completely released from its housing.

Comment: Sounds like something James Bond would use? https://jamesbond.fandom.com/wiki/Eurocopter_AS355

Comment: @TKK that would make sense, wouldn't it? We don't want sense! We want chainsaw planes! bzzzzzzzzzzzztttt!

Comment: @JuhaUntinen that was my initial thought too. Those aren't restricted to fictional stories either, plenty of utility companies take advantage of them - https://www.google.com/search?q=aerial+side-trimmer

Comment: I've just removed the "reality-check" tag from the question, since the very first thing you must do to atempt answering is forbiding anything related to reality.

Comment: If you're going for rule of cool, the explosive options mentioned in this video seem like good candidates: youtube.com/watch?v=ckSoDW2-wrc

Answer (score 125):

**Giant coiled spring.**

It would uncoil itself and drive the chain.  It would provide loads of power on demand.  Storing that kind of energy as a coiled spring is dangerous, but I see that as a positive thing for your scenario.

Comment: +1 for being rechargeable

Comment: I'd go with this.  See also  Bacigalupi's WIndup Girl series -- with genetically designed organic springs as energy sources.

Comment: I like this. It's not very realistic, but it sure as heck is cool..

Comment: @JohnDvorak Ah yes, the quest for a realistic power source for a single use jet-delivered chainsaw.

Comment: I like it as super practical.  Any electric source requires an electric motor.  This is the energy source and the source of rotational motion, all in one package.

Comment: Spring tension can hold the drive train together as well.  When the spring looses tension it could literally fall apart as the question suggests.  If you've ever taken apart a tape measure and had a part slip out of your hands you'll get what I'm talking about.

Comment: There’s only one problem with this idea — it lacks the blood curdling scream of the real thing. Is there a way we could integrate a sound to amplify the intimidation factor? Maybe have the spring clip against a metallic resonator for a low, rhythmic, rumbling, clank.

Answer (score 39):

Pyrotechnics, in the form of twin spinning rockets rotating the saw axle. You have jet fighters, missiles would look like an obvious option. And as a bonus, a faulty device would explode throwing shrapnel into the enemy.

Comment: I think I like this, not because it is the best answer, but because it is sooo bad that it fits perfectly with an air-dropped, single use, 400lb chainsaw.

Answer (score 29):

[Capacitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor). These are electric components which store an electric charge for a limited amount of time and can release it very rapidly. They are relatively cheap and easy to manufacture. They are also reusable, but that doesn't matter in this case.

Capacitors can be manufactured in many different ways depending on their desired characteristics. But in general they have a lower energy density than chemical power cells, but they can release their stored energy a lot faster.

Capacitors are usually not designed to hold a charge for longer than a couple hours, so the capacitors either need to be charged before the mission or during the mission from the fighter's internal power supply.

Comment: "... usually not designed to hold a charge..." ??  Depends drastically on the application.  Whatever you do, never touch the flyback capacitor on a CRT without shorting it first.  They hold significant voltage for years.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, years is a bit of an exaggeration. The self discharge rate of capacitors (as in no bleeder resistors) is still in the range of days. Supercapacitors have a lower self discharge rate but is still not remotely in the realm of years. Though, I'm always happy to be wrong, I did some quick checking but maybe I missed some edge case where that's true.

Comment: Capacitor 'hold time' depends on design and materials used. While they'll slowly leak it is well within the realm of possibility to design such a capacitor that could be charged on loading of the weapon and last for a 6-12 hour mission with useful load. Also keep in mind that 'discharged' doesn't always mean 'empty' - Very large caps can still hold enough to give you a solid kick years later, even if they're well below 'useful' levels that it was intended to be used at. In short: Don't lick caps.

Comment: I updated the answer in light of the recent comments.

Comment: @TheLuckless if it's possible for it to hold charge years later, why can't you make us of that to develop a capacitor that holds charge for years?

Comment: @NathanHinchey, almost all capacitors that 'hold a charge' years later have actually self-charged, just a little bit. Industrial capacitors have to be stored with the terminals shorted out or they can hurt the next person who goes to touch them. There's no useful power really, but they can get to a couple of percent of their voltage rating if you leave them alone.

Answer (score 26):

Launching from a plane, that chainsaw is going to waste a lot of nice gravitational energy, which could be used for much more interesting tasks, such as providing motion to the chainsaw itself.

So, the chainsaw itself is tethered to the plane with a very long roller chain, which is connected to a pinion inside the chainsaw (think of a Beyblade launcher).
When launched from  the plane, the chainsaw falls, so that the roller chain makes the pinion start rotating. The pinion will then transmit the motion to the chainsaw, so that it will rotate at full speed when touching ground!

Alternatively, a parachute could open and hold a reel with the roller chain tethered to the chainsaw, which is still falling relative to the parachute.

Comment: basically a flywheel, charged by gravity

Comment: This could cause the chainsaw to fall more slowly, as some of it's gravitational energy is being co-opted to spin it. How about letting the chainsaw fall with a slack roller chain, then when the person catches it, the roller chain, which is still attached to the jet, gets yanked away by the jet, starting the chainsaw. Like a combination of launching a beyblade and using a string attached to your dog's collar to yank a loose tooth out.

Comment: +1 for beating even the "pyrotechnics" answer in how ridiculously entertaining it would be to see.

Comment: As the person who wrote the pyrotechnics answer, I can't but totally agree with mtraceur. This is better cool-for-buck hands down.

Answer (score 18):

I would go for a pneumatic solution. It can support easily a 40 pound high pressure container storing sufficient energy for 15 seconds.

Comment: Also consider the giant farting sound on, ahem, discharge. Use methane as the gas, and then light the exhaust, and use the flame jets. IDK how, but use them.

Comment: @Neal simple: what's better than a chainsaw at maiming your enemy? The MurderCo Rocket-Propelled Chainsaw (patents pending)! Why use measly human (or whatever other species) appendages to thrust your chainsaw into your enemy when our patented diverters use the combustion exhaust to *launch* it at your enemy? Warning, adult supervision required, MurderCo is not responsible for loss of limbs or life, property damage, or damages caused by Acts of Stupid (which includes all actions taken using the MurderCo RPC).

Comment: A flatulentic turbocharged curled discharge. Are we still talking about Taco Bell?

Comment: The tacos in the chainsaw's taco dispenser gotta come from somewhere. I can see Taco Bell doing fine as the preferred taco contractor.

Answer (score 16):

While the question does not explicitly specify this, I think it is reasonable to specify some, er, specifications.

- **Extreme energy density**. The goal of this weapon seems to be to deliver as much destruction as possible in 15 seconds, in a 400lb package which is probably the weight limit for the weapon stores on the jet. It is desirable that the majority of this 400lb is gnawing teeth of mushy annihilation, and only a small part is fuel and power source.
- **Extreme reliability**. If a air-dropped 400lb giant disposable chainsaw seems like the best way out of a situation, you are probably in *deep, deep* trouble. You don't want to be yanking a starter cord on a dodgy two-stroke while the Tentacles of Kaza'An the Soul Destroyer of Mag-Uhn squeeze the life out of your fellow unlucky party members. You shouldn't have to carefully lubricate the moving parts of your jammed chainsaw while the Teeth of Brig-Wrath the Extirpator of Zw'n-Thragg dismember your group members. You want to have instant destruction available the moment you receive the weapon. You might even want to be able to use the device on Frizhger the Mauling Shark-Fish, submerged in the Sea of Despair.

Obviously, air-breathing engines are no good, what with the underwater Mauling Shark-Fish (also, the torrential rains on Zw'n-Thragg!). Electrics are really not great either - they require careful isolation from the environment, and frankly, the energy density of batteries is quite terrible - you don't want to run out of power halfway one of Kaza'An's Tentacles.

The obvious solution is a hydrazine turbine engine. Hydrazine is an extremely reactive fuel, that does not need an external source of oxygen. It is used as a rocket fuel (where energy density is key). A turbine engine probably has the highest power-to-weight ratio of any rotating engine, and furthermore it only has a single moving part, which can be connected with a single reduction gear to the saw chain. The reaction products of running hydrazine over a catalyst such as iridium are extremely hot nitrogen and hydrogen gas, the latter of which can also combust once it does come into contact with the outside air.

The end result is a screeching whining chainsaw of death spitting blue flames from its exhaust. Chances are the extirpation days of Brig-Wrath are soon over.

Comment: I like your logic, but why bother with the complexity of a turbine and reduction gearing when you could **put hydrazine rockets on the chain itself**

Comment: @Robin I considered that but half of the rockets will be facing the chainsaw operators. An alternative is to have a rocket pointing directly at the chain but in these case the chain needs to be a compromise between gnawy teethiness and power transfer. All in all I liked the turbine option best.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the kinds of circumstances required for this kind of weapon and delivery system to even be considered.

Comment: @Perkins Circumstances such as, but not limited to, the examples listed above. :)

Comment: What's worse is with all these heroes wielding hydrazine-fuelled chainsaws, the environment on Zw'n-Thragg has gone to Mag-Uhn in a handcart. There are no trees left on the one small continent of Baf'tarn, and acid rain has caused the Mauling Shark-Fish to get slightly more agitated, which attracts more hydrazine-fuelled heroes. smh

Comment: @MerseyViking No need to be so negative! The decomposition products of hydrazine are hydrogen, nitrogen and ammonia. Only the latter is mildly toxic in elevated quantities, but does not case acid rain. The only real problem is the Miak Salmon infestation - a rare fish that uses proton pumps in its gills to convert dissolved ammonia to a liquorice-like substance dubbed Sal'Miak by the local population.

Comment: After reading this comment I thought to myself: surely some unwise person has tried putting Hydrazine in an ICE, right? Yep! [Drag racing pioneers or suicidal nutjobs?](https://euclidsbridge.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/drag-racing-pioneers-or-suicidal-nutjobs/)

Answer (score 11):

As an alternative to coiled spring you can have your own gyro core (or [flywheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flywheel_energy_storage)).

Make a small and dense wheel to rotate very fast on pins in your chainsaw, virtually without energy loss, and then give it all away to chain blades. After it is discharged it becomes a useless piece of metal without any electronics or stuff. It is also much safer to operate than coiled spring.

If anything it will also stabilize delivery of this chainsaw.

Comment: Trying to manoeuvre such a weapon would be nigh on impossible if you used it to store any appreciable energy, surely?

Comment: You could put your gyro core into gyro stabilizer, which will let you handle such weapon. Or maybe it's not even necessary given the question details.

Comment: Probably storing the spun up weapons in opposite-spun pairs always would compensate some unwanted effect AND stabilize your aircraft?

Comment: Just use counter-rotating gyros.

Answer (score 7):

Well if you only need it very briefly I'd recommend a power cell.

Where batteries provide a slow trickle of stored energy over time,power cells can dump all of their energy in an instant. So that chainsaw purpose built to be disposable but very deadly could literally be torn apart from the energy it exerts in its short period of activity.

Also this means that being disposable the chainsaw would be made of cheaper materials. Since the power cell never needs to be replaced as it is a one-off use it can be made non-rechargeable and self-destructing. Not in the way it blows up when used, but it burns out the internal storage from the incredible heat and shock of the energy release.

All in all, the chainsaws shall exist. And they shall be terrifying. Maybe just make the edge out of carbon nano-tubes? Nano-tubes can also be used to store energy within their mass much like batteries or power cells. So you could literally make the chainsaw one giant power cell made of an extremely energy dense but light material that at 400 lbs would have enough power to immolate an elephant entirely most likely.

Your chainsaw would have the power of a bomb, all put towards a few glorious seconds to a minute at most of incredibly destructive power as the blade super heats and the chainsaw loses cohesion as the power which simultaneously kept it together suddenly runs out.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Aren't batteries and power cells the same thing? A battery is a group of several cells linked together. If you cut open something like an AA battery, you will find button cells inside of it. Even car batteries are made up of several different cells.

Comment: @LiamMorris In fact, it may even be the opposite: each power gives you some power, so you want as many as possible to have the highest possible power (but for the shortest time)

Comment: Maybe use super capacitors. They can deliver huge amount of power in short time.

Comment: @jnovacho Good idea. I will write an answer based on this.

Comment: What's this power cell you are talking about?

Comment: That would be an individual element from a battery. As @LiamMorris points out, "battery" means "several of <something> together". Hence gun batteries, or batteries of tests. In a rechargeable battery, the element is an accumulator. You can also theoretically make capacitor batteries, or even superconducting solenoid batteries. In a non-rechargeable battery (as may be the case here), we would probably talk about generator.

Comment: That moment where tired me put power cell instead of fuel cell. -.- I am talking about fuel cells made using carbon nano-tubes.

Comment: When you say power cell, do you mean something like a molten salt battery?  Pyrotechnic initiation, with very high currents for a limited amount of time.  Used on missiles.

Comment: @LiamMorris  AA "batteries" don't generally have multiple cells unless you're talking about some really uncommon chemistries.  They are, technically AA cells.  Same applies for AAA, AAAA, A, B, C, D and N cells.  9 volt batteries and 6 volt lantern batteries and such are actually batteries and have multiple cells inside them, as do 12 volt automotive batteries and many electronic devices' battery packs. (Cell phones often run on a single 5v lithium cell though, lithium is potent stuff.)

Comment: @Perkins I know that some do, i remember a few years back i had a battery but the plastic coating was peeling off. Out of pure curiosity, i pulled off the covering and found that it was just a bunch of button cells. It might have been a Duracell battery but i cant remember.

Answer (score 4):

Googling "battery in missiles" led me to the page of a company manufacturing and selling such solutions.

I am guessing your solution would be "[thermal battery](https://www.eaglepicher.com/technology/battery-chemistries/thermal-battery/)". I do not think they are selling a solution just for you but the duration and power can be tailored to application. Also, such batteries are used by military using similar "mil-tech" would probably fit the back story.

Also such batteries are single use, durable, reliable and have long shelf life.

Some of the other battery chemistries they offer might work better for you, so you might want to check them out. They might be rechargeable though.

Comment: Also known as "molten salt battery"

Answer (score 4):

The parameters of the problem are:

1. Single-use ordnance
2. Power-to-weight is a significant constraint
3. Brief duration of discharge
4. Cheap-ish (we're talking about a **disposable giant chainsaw** here)

So you're probably looking at a chemical energy source that needs to be converted to mechanical energy. That rules out any high-explosive, and anyway, explosives expend much of their energy in brisance.

Fuels like **Otto II** driving a turbine are one possibility, if you'd like the system to be self-contained (i.e. not subject the user to exhaust fumes). If that is not a serious consideration (e.g. you are okay with a fire-belching disposable giant chainsaw), then the parameters of the problem closely resemble the energy requirements of a **rocket.**

I'm partial to a powderized-aluminum + ammonium nitrate mixture, myself.

Answer (score 2):

Well possibly the easiest power source to use would be a battery, you can accurately determine how much ‘life’ it could give to a piece of electronics by setting the max capacity and charging it until it is full.

Although, if your problem is just that you need to get the chainsaws down safely, i would recommend using parachutes or heavily padded drop boxes to ensure the contents were undamaged. At that point you could use whatever fuel you liked as it would not be damaged from the fall.

However, i don’t think you’d want to use chainsaws, especially ones that heavy, as weapons. They are not particularly effective, are slow and 400 pounds is about the weight of two humans. At that point you might as well be using a giant maul instead. [Here is an answer where i explained the issues with chainsaw weapons.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/143129/62187) There is also a link to a youtube video in my answer which demonstrates my point.

Comment: But chainsaws are **FUN**  .  Signed, Anonymous From Texas

Answer (score 2):

Since this is the sort of weapon that Coyote would be using against Roadrunner, it must be powered by the future power supply du jour.

In the 1950s that would have meant nuclear power, nowadays everything is battery powered, though some consider that the future is in hydrogen.

It very much depends on the tone of the situation you're creating.

The clean and neat nature of modern hydrogen fuel cells and batteries may not fit the context, so you might want to find some way of making it spew smoke and fire as it's powered up, that means coal or at the least diesel powered.

Comment: If you're looking for something in an 'industrial' style (spewing fire and smoke) where it doesn't have to work for very long, and is insensitive to the health of the users, you could go for boron-doped 'zip' fuels, used in aircraft and rockets, and should be roughly compatible with diesel engines (at least briefly!) As an added bonus: the flames are green!

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a chemistry based solution. Think of current engines; they are all based on the concept of explosions. Now think of a giant explosion happening on release of the chainsaw. It would create enough pressure to power the chainsaw for quite some time.

Answer (score 2):

While not a chain saw, much of the effect could be delivered cheaply and reliably by a 400lb coiled spring, which has saw teeth etched into the edges. This can be deployed from the plane itself (uncoiling and lashing at the target as the plane screams overhead. Alternatively, the hero can be braced with his back to a tree or a wall and pull out the pin or cut the cord holding the coil closed, it lashes out like an [Urumi](https://blog.knife-depot.com/urumi-whip-sword/) from hell, striking with considerable kinetic energy and razor sharp cutting teeth.

[image]

As you can imagine, there is nothing close to what I am describing. Take this, increase the size to account for the 400lbs of spring steel, serrate the edges and have a cord or pin holding it closd against the spring tension

Considering a 400 lb coil of spring steel would actually be quite long, you would also have a considerable advantage of reach over most opponents, who would either think the plane is too low to drop a bomb, or the hero is too far away from then (and whatever is that drum like object he is holding?), so fail to take proper precautions.

Answer (score 2):

Build the chainsaw with a heavy flywheel.  Add a heavy duty piston/foot that the chainsaw lands on when dropped towards you.  When that piston hits ground at high collision speeds it spins up the flywheel, which directly powers the chain.  You run over and grab it, go to work for your 15 seconds of glory.

No power source beyond gravity and the flywheel needed.  Being all mechanical and built tough it possibly wouldn't even fall apart, later it gets picked up and reset for another drop.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Willk's answer here:

You have a "lander" and a chainsaw. The chainsaw is spring-powered. The lander has multiple rotors, say 3, that both break the fall and charge spring. It would basically look like a quadrocopter with a chainsaw at the bottom falling down.

A ratchet prevents the spring from discharging. A trigger mechanism in the chainsaw releases the ratchet and directs its power from the rotor coupling to the saw's chain - the chainsaw is running, purely from the energy from the fall.

Answer (score 1):

Dual liquid explosive, the force would trash the mechanism but its a one use weapon.

Comment: These are normally called binary explosives, just for reference.

Answer (score 1):

### Coffman (shotgun) starter

The [Coffman starter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffman_engine_starter)  uses a propellant fit in a shotgun shell, with the standard shotgun primer (blasting cap).  It generates up to 15 seconds of pneumatic force to start [large aviation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65qrzgbTTcQ) and [tractor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idwceKeWgHw) engines.

Famously used on the movie *Flight of the Phoenix* (both versions).

Adjust size for energy need, but it's just the right energy density, weight and burn rate for the job.

Answer (score 1):

If a massive chainsaw is deployed from a jet, it should be powered by Mr. Torgue's specialty. The large weight is needed to contain and direct the C4 detonation inside to spin the chain. Maybe also the back side is stronger than the front, creating the possibility for the chain blade to launch through the enemy.

Answer (score 1):

**THE IDEAL POWER SOURCE ON ACCOUNT OF SHEER INSANITY FACTOR**

The setting already seems insane enough, so let's go all-out.

The chainsaw is powered by a gigantic, 100-pound explosive. When it drops into the user's hands, the explosives detonate. The energy of the resultant explosion is funneled through a contraption of piping that directs it first to spin a turbine, which gets the chain up to speed, and then backward and out some 'exhaust thrusters' which help the user charge towards the target despite the chainsaw's incredible weight. Basically, it's a missile, and the user is there to point it in the right direction.

Is it safe? No. But neither is dropping a 400-pound chainsaw in front of somebody so they can use it as a glass cannon-style weapon.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a power source.

Humans generally have a terminal speed of 53m/s. Your chainsaw, due to weight and profile, will probably have a greater final velocity.

A 400 pounds piece of metal hitting you at 53m/s will impart you with approximately 2.54 x 10<sup>8</sup> joules, or ~ 70,555.5 wh. That's equivalent to the detonation of around 60~65 kilograms of TNT. It will turn the target to a pulp just by its kinetic delivery, as well as anyone else nearby.